# Tile logfile into pieces and search for errors

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I want to tile a logfile into pieces and then search in this pieces for errors. If there is an error, I want to put the relevant logfile-piece into another file.

Little example:

Logfile looks like this:

> STARTLOG1
>   blabla
>   more_blabla
>   ENDLOG1
>   STARTLOG2
>   ERROR: Errortext
>   This is an Error
>   from user XYZ
>   ENDLOG2
>   STARTLOG3
>   blabla
>   more_blabla
>   ENDLOG3

I want to tile logfile into pieces. All lines between STARTLOG and ENDLOG should be 1 piece. When an error appears in a piece, extract the whole piece to a file.
The file should look like this:

> STARTLOG2
>   ERROR: Errortext
>   This is an Error
>   from user XYZ
>   ENDLOG2

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ awk -v RS="STARTLOG" '/ERROR/{print RS$0; }' log
STARTLOG2
ERROR: Errortext
This is an Error
from user XYZ
ENDLOG2
```

To redirect to a file called `logN` where N is the number from `STARTLOG`, use:

```
gawk -v RS="STARTLOG" '/ERROR/{print RS$0 > "log"$1; }' log
```

#### Explanation

`RS` is the record separator, it's what defines what a "line" is for `awk`. Here, I'm setting it to `STARTLOG` so that the entire record is treated as a single line. Then, if that "line" contains `ERROR`, I print `STARTLOG` (the `RS`, this is just to recreate the same format).

You can also use the same approach with Perl:

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN{$/="STARTLOG"}{print "$/$_" if /ERROR/}' log
```